# When does the *Window focus* change in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, focus, window

In my project, I need to catch the Window focus change. I have logged out the results for all the stages of an activity. When the screen is on, the result is as follows:

```
02-17 13:50:03.898: DEBUG/InquiryInterface(3829): onCreate screen state : false
02-17 13:50:03.898: DEBUG/InquiryInterface(3829): onStart screen state : false
02-17 13:50:03.898: DEBUG/InquiryInterface(3829): onResume screen state : false
02-17 13:50:08.998: DEBUG/InquiryInterface(3829): onPause screen state : true
02-17 13:50:09.178: DEBUG/InquiryInterface(3829): onWindowFocusChanged : false
02-17 13:50:09.228: DEBUG/InquiryInterface(3829): onStop screen state : false
02-17 13:50:09.228: DEBUG/InquiryInterface(3829): onDestroy screen state : false
```

onWindowFocusChanged is the method provided by the class Activity. And the value shown in the list is the input value(boolean hasFocus) of the method onWindowFocusChanged.

I have used the following code to get the state of window focus for every state of the method, onCreate, onStart, etc.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate screen state : "+String.valueOf(this.hasWindowFocus()));
}
```

But in the Android documention, I read : the method onResume() is **Called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it.**

So in this way, I should get "True" for the window focus within onResume, but not in onPause(). Anyone has an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My understanding of it is the opposite of what you say. onResume() gets called just before your activity gets focus, and onPause gets called just before it loses focus. I could have sworn I read it this way somewhere but I can't seem to find where I saw it in the [Activity Lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Comment: I have just go through the whole life cycle of the activity with more logs, and I have got the same conclusion as yours. Thanks, I have accpeted your answer. Didn't know it before:)

Comment: From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29): _"Note that this provides information about global focus state, which is managed independently of activity lifecycles. As such, while focus changes will generally have some relation to lifecycle changes (an activity that is stopped will not generally get window focus), you should not rely on any particular order between the callbacks here and those in the other lifecycle methods such as onResume()."_

Comment: NO! (but usually yes). Pull down the notification bar while our activity is resumed - this will cause its window to loose the focus. There are windows that not backed with activities (Notification Bar is one of them, or system alert windows). Those windows do NOT cause the foreground activity to be paused, but they can gain the focus.

Answer (score -1):

By the time `onResume()` is called, your activity already has focus. That's what the docs are telling you.

Comment: Yes, I agree. So should I get "true" for the window focus state if I am within onResume()?

Comment: This is not true. onResume gets called before the window has focus. If you bring up your activity and then put your phone to sleep, when you turn on the power button, your activity's onResume will be called, and you will be staring at the lock screen. Only after the lock screen is dismissed does onWindowFocusChange get called. Good explanation here: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/11/making-android-games-that-play-nice.html

Comment: @Tim - I take your point. It's interesting though, that the [docs for the Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) say: _"Called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it."_ The definition of focus, as far as I know, is where user activity goes. (Granted, documentation later on contradicts this, but that was the source of my mistake.)

Comment: No problem. I know this is old, just wanted to leave a comment for any future visitors to this question. Assuming that your activity is visible on the screen during or immediately after onResume is a dangerous assumption. I too wish the docs were a little clearer.

Comment: _Keep in mind that **`onResume` is not the best indicator that your activity is visible to the user**; a system window such as the keyguard may be in front. Use `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)` to know for certain that your activity is visible to the user_ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()