# Reliable way to know if a window has the focus?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a reliable way to know if a window has the focus.

I already read the documentation of [`onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()), which says: *Keep in mind that onResume is not the best indicator that your activity is visible to the user; a system window such as the keyguard may be in front. Use `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)` to know for certain that your activity is visible to the user*. 
Then I read the docs for [`onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)), which says:*Called when the current Window of the activity gains or loses focus*. **Q1) Does this mean that `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)` blocks instead of using a callback?**

I also read [Making Android Games that Play Nice](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/11/making-android-games-that-play-nice.html) and [When does the *Window focus* change in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025311/when-does-the-window-focus-change-in-android).

And came up with:

```
@Override
protected void onResume () {
    super.onResume();
    if(!hasWindowFocus()) // I don't want to wait for a windowFocusChanged event if this window already has the focus
        onWindowFocusChanged(true); // I assume this method blocks
    //This window has the focus.... do stuff
    //...
}
```

**Q2) Does this code ensures that the window has the focus?**

Thanks

Comment: @Shashank thanks. I didn't because I'm not sure how to handle `false` from `requestFocus()`.

Comment: I thought it means you need to override `onWindowFocusChanged`?

Answer (score 1):

To confirm that your activity is in focus or is visible to user, you can start a service in background which keeps checking the topmost activity.

For checking top most activity use following.

```
Context context = someArbitraryContext;
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
String className = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
```

If package name and class name matches to yours, means that your activity is in focus.

**Note**: Dont forgot to add `android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"` permission in your manifest

Hop it helps you.

Comment: Thanks. Having a service in the background to check looks a like an overkill to me. Ingenious tho.

Comment: I think having one more permission for such a task is an overkill... nevertheless, ingenious solution.